# I get a different html page using Ctrl+u and curl

Tags: command-line, curl

When I go to a this web-page (https://imgur.com/user/Ultraruben/submitted for example) and press `Ctrl+u`, I get one web-page. When I try to extract the html through the command line with `curl <url>` or `curl -L <url>` I get another.
`lynx -dump <url>` doesn't work either (no javascript).

I need to get through the command line (with whatever tool that works) the same I get through my browser with `Ctrl+u`.

This is what I got through the Opera browser: https://justpaste.it/42ci1
And this is with curl: https://justpaste.it/9oy3g

Comment: Activate developer tools on Opera, have a look at the networking tab, export request that lead to your page as curl. That may still not give you the exact page if the page is modified by Javascript...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty common for web sites to react to the kind of client they're seeing with different content.

Some of that is well-intended: For example, some websites go through lengths to support incredibly old phones or windows PCs. From a security point of perspective, you'd want to tell an Internet Explorer 5 user that they need to update – but your job might be to help get health information to the public, not to tell people with no money that they need to buy a new laptop.

Sometimes you need to support an old gaming device with a specifically quirky website to make its browser happy, or deliver a version of the site optimized for the screen.

Anyway, that's likely what's happening here; your curl sends "Hey, I'm curl", the webserver reacts with a page specifically for automated tools, not for browsers.

So, first: check whether things solve if you tell curl to use the same user-agent as your main browser. Maybe that already solves things.

If you say lynx doesn't work because it doesn't do JavaScript, then, well, you need something that does all the JavaScript a modern browser does. That means it needs to be a modern browser. There's ways to puppeteer browsers from a command line. In essence, you're looking for *WebDriver*.

This won't work without you writing a few lines of script. [Mozilla's WebDriver documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebDriver) has an example that might get you started. You will want to add some waiting (on a completion of load, plus some fractions of a second) to allow for JavaScript to complete, before you get the source code. The example does that by waiting for a specific element to start existing.

Comment: So, basically ignore cURL and wget tools and move to browser automation when I encounter problems?

Comment: Depends, and I made quite a significant distinction where you would need that.

Answer (score 0):

[Use the option `-H`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31597823/402322) to set the [`User-Agent` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent).

If you use Firefox, you can open the network analyser and right click on a get request. Next select "Copy as cURL address" from the context menu. For the URL `cr.yp.to`, you will get the following command:

```
curl 'http://cr.yp.to/' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1'
```